# Python script to search excel files in a folder for unique strings then rename/append file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I've got 10 years worth of old testing data. There's couple of different test types and their results in the excel spreadsheets but they were not done in a templatized way so their file names don't really tell you what data is inside of them. I want to write a python script to go through each file in the folder and look for a unique string and then based on that string, append the file name or move them into new file folders so I can then start working on the data extraction.

So I've got this initial piece done, but I need to understand how to make it loop through all the files and then change the name or move it to a folder? I'm going to ultimately try and scrape all this data into their new corresponding database tables but I want to make sure I get the data type organized first. Any recommendations are much appreciated.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
shiftcol = 5 # offset from 'Report' cell
shiftrow = 5

found = False
for sn in wb.sheetnames:  # all sheets in workbook
   if found: break
   ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sn)
   for cl in range(1,51):  # search 50 columns
      if found: break
      for rw in range(1,51):   # search 50 rows
          if found: break
          if ws.cell(rw,cl).value == 'Report':  # search for first cell with this value
              print('Found Report. Sheet='+sn+' Col=' + str(cl) + ' Row=' + str(rw))
              found = True 

if not found:
   print ("Report field not found") # didn't find cell with 'Report'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Python, so not sure if this is along the lines of what you are looking for:

```
import glob
import shutil

fmask = '[YOUR PATH]/*.xlsx'

dfs = []
for f in glob.glob(fmask):
    f = f.replace(r'[YOUR PATH]', '')
    original = r'[ORIGINAL PATH]' + f
    target = r'[TARGET PATH]' + f
    shutil.copyfile(original, target)
```

What this does is loop through all of the files in the [YOUR PATH] folder, replaces the [YOUR PATH] part of the string with nothing and then copies them over to the [TARGET PATH] appended by the individual file name.

There are probably more efficient ways of doing this, but it works for me.